# Saving smallest JPG possible with Photoshop

Tags: web, save, jpeg, photoshop, shrink

I wanted to know what the best way to save a JPG to be very small like less than 100kb and still keep it's quality a bit. i have 1200x1200 psd files in Photoshop
and the best i get is like 500kb-600kb, is there any third party software that shrinks? any other method?

any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you using `Save for Web`?

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow below steps.

Step: 1  File> Export > Save for Web

Step: 2  Choose Jpeg or Png as per your need.

Step: 3 Save it.

Step: 4 Now Open your Browser.

Step: 5 Open this link  [**https://tinypng.com/**](https://tinypng.com/)

Step: 6 Drag or Upload your exported image.

Download it.

That's it!

Hope it will work for you!

Thank you,

Nirav Mistry